# Unhandled rejection MongoError: port must be specified

Tags: node.js, mongoose

According to [the Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) you can connect to a MongoDB with a default port of 27017.

My `mongod` output ends with:

```
 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

But when I try and connect to my database like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');
```

I get

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: port must be specified
```

What is happening here?

I have Mongoose v5.2.0, node v9.10.0, and MongoDB shell version v4.0.0.

If I change my connection string to include the port `mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp` then I am able to connect. But I'm not sure why I need this.

Comment: The only place I can find this error is [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/server.js.html) which is the source code for MongoDb native 2.0

Comment: Default port is definitely optional, this puzzles me.

Comment: @AlexisFacques I'm sure it's a problem with some version of something, like node, or mongoose or mongodb.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Mongoose maintainer here, sorry about the trouble. We'll fix [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6647) within the next couple days. Until then, please specify the port in your URI: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');`. We'll also make sure to update the [relevant docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Comment: Fantastic! This is what makes open source + Stack Overflow great.

Answer (score 5):

Port should also be specified in mongoose.connect() in the latest version of mongoose (5.2.0):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/cat_app");
```

27017 is MongoDB's default port on which mongod is running.

Another solution is to revert to mongoose 5.1.7 which won't cause this issue:

```
npm install mongoose@5.1.7 --save
```

Let me know if that fixes it.